# What is the confirmation distribution type that is shown here on traviota.iotalt.com?

Tags: confirmation

Looking at [traviota.iotalt.com](http://traviota.iotalt.com/), the 7 day, 7000+ sample confirmation time frequency in minutes is charted as follows:

[image: 7daychart]

It is characterized by an onset min value of 29 seconds, an attack peak at 4 minutes, and a decay that finishes at 358 minutes (shown only to 30 minutes on 
 the chart).

What type of distribution is this?

How is this different from the theoretical Tangle distribution confirmation form when the network is fully optimized (running to spec)?

Comment: There will not be a fully optimized tangle in near distant future. It's evolving constantly especially with special hardware added. All parameters (see alpha, darcy's crater) are dependant on hardware and topology. I would say your image shows a healthy distribution for current tangle topology

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is Poisson distribution. If we are waiting for independent event to occur, time **when** it will occur is distributed according to [Poisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution). Optimized tangle or not, it will be Poisson, just parameters might change. It also depends of measurement itself, of course.

Below confirmation time distribution in 16 days, 17300+ samples
[image: ****]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82090/discussion-on-answer-by-lunfardo-what-is-the-confirmation-distribution-type-that).